# sed or awk to grab multi pattern and print

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to extract from a bash result file the path and the shortname of user but I realy don't know how to parse it with sed or awk

This is an example of 1lined result to arrange.

```
"drwxr-xr-x+","2","adm","com.apple.local.ard_admin","68","Sep","7","23:17","/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS","0: user:d_zeiger inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"1: user:f_mure inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"2: group:projet_gestion_temps_plannings_ls inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"3: group:css_et_cs_pole45_bsi_drh inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"4: user:us9-2_cadre inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"5: user:css_ltd inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"6: user:c_naegel inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"7: user:d_zeiger inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"8: user:us3_soins inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"9: user:css_ltd inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"10: user:extrahosp_s4_cadre inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"11: user:p_triantafyllidis inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"12: user:us_3 inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"13: user:a_burglen inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"14: user:d_spiess inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"15: user:s_kling inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"16: user:hopjour_cadre_s4 inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"17: user:mc_broggini inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,"18: user:c_faffa inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit"
```

I need to extract `/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS` (the path an always the 9 data) and for example `user:us_3` (who can be in any position after the path)

Comment: What is `user:us_3`? There are many `user:something`.

Comment: yes pacholik, user:accountname

Comment: Before downvoting: do you want to retrieve al users? What should your output look like?

Comment: Your CSV is broken: every field following field9 is missing the end quote.

Comment: Tx a lot all. I've correct my script who parse the csv file. I'vnt see the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your question is clear: get directory from column 9 if there is a user `us_3` defined somewhere in the line.

Solution with **GNU awk**:

```
$ awk -F, -v usr=us_3 '$0 ~ "user:"usr{print gensub(/"/,"","g",$9)}' input.txt
/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS
```

OR solution with **mawk**

```
$ awk -F, -v usr=us_3 '$0 ~ "user:"usr{gsub(/"/, "");print $9}' input.txt
/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS
```

Comment: @MarkLambrichs Tx. But I get this error `awk: calling undefined function gensub
 input record number 936, file test_acl_kling.csv
 source line number 1` I'm under MacOS. I think this fonction of awk isn't implemented.

Comment: I'm on macosx as well. Apparently you don't have gnu awk. Try the second solution.

Comment: @MarkLambrichs !! Super genial !! it works as well I need. Tx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Finds last `user:something`

```
$ sed -E 's/^("[^"]*",){8}"([^"]*)".*(user:[^ ]+).*/\2|\3/' file
/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS|user:c_faffa
```

Finds `user:ussomething`

```
$ sed -E 's/^("[^"]*",){8}"([^"]*)".*(user:us[^ ]+).*/\2|\3/' file
/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS|user:us_3
```

Finds `user:us_3`

```
$ sed -E 's/^("[^"]*",){8}"([^"]*)".*(user:us_3) .*/\2|\3/' file
/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS|user:us_3
```

`\1` contains eight cells, `\2` nineth. `\3` contains user.

Comment: user:something => problem, this is not the user I want to search specifically. If I change user: [^] by user: d_zeiger [^] this no longer works

Comment: @ThomasLabarre added regex for specific user

Comment: `sed -E 's/^("[^"]*",){8}"([^"]*)".*(user:us[^ ]+).*/\2|\3/'` won't work  with my example above or any other `user:ussomething` . I forgot something in the code?

Comment: @ThomasLabarre How could I possibly know? Are those three examples not enough for you? What does it mean it won't work? Do you have any errors? Do you you have different outputs? Do you have different set of data? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to ask for help, because I always ended up finding. But now I'm stuck. My Masters of SED/AWK reached its limit... In fact, there is no errors, but the command does not extract the Path part `/ Volumes /... ` nor the part `user:ussomething` want to retrieve. My file remain as it is

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper CSV parser for CSV data.

If I fix your CSV, I can use ruby to do:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  $stdin.each_line do |line|
    CSV.parse(line) do |row|
      result = row[9..-1].inject([row[8]]) do |res, elem|
        if m = elem.match(/\buser:(\w+)/)
          res << m[1]
        end
        res
      end
      puts CSV.generate_line result, :force_quotes => true
    end
  end
' < file.csv
```

```
"/Volumes/raid-partages/POLE LTD/Plannings mensuels et hebdos LTD/Z Archive Planning CS LTD/Planning 2017 ds dossier CS","d_zeiger","f_mure","us9","css_ltd","c_naegel","d_zeiger","us3_soins","css_ltd","extrahosp_s4_cadre","p_triantafyllidis","us_3","a_burglen","d_spiess","s_kling","hopjour_cadre_s4","mc_broggini","c_faffa"
```

Comment: tx @glenn jackman, but I need to find specific user. My obejectif is to find each directory to which it has access